# Defining matrix functions on higher dimensional tensors? Specifically a matrix logarithm

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, linear-algebra, logarithm

Pytorch does not have a native matrix logarithm. I would like to create an efficient logarithm using 'scipy.linalg.logm'. The problem is that 'logm' can only be applied to square tensors. I would like to compute the log of a tensor shape (64,22,3,3), in which the log is being applied to the (3,3) matrix component. Is there a fast and efficient way to apply logm to the entire tensor?

I currently am resorting to list comprehension which is incredibly slow:

```
x=torch.rand(64,22,3,3)
Log_x=torch.stack([logm(x[i,j]) for i in range(x.shape[0]) for j in range(x.shape[1])])
```

Comment: Not sure I follow - why would torch.log() not be suitable?

Comment: @paisanco torch.log() applies the scalar log function to each entry of the tensor. The matrix logarithm is an operation that is applied to the entire matrix and in general is not the same as applying the scalar logarithm entry-wise.

Comment: Similar question, still unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706038